# Filter criteria field Timestamp value <= now

Tags: views

is it possible to filter a timestamp field against 'now' or 'today' value.

it works very well with any Date field but i can't make it with a timestamp.

the timestamp filter works if i put avalue of unix-timestamp type (1654792580 for instance)

Comment: it seems this is a missing feature... how to report it? the filter timestamp should propose the alternate time offset entry like the date filter do.

Comment: Could you provide some more context on where you are doing the filtering? i.e. in a hook, with view, etc

Comment: This is in a view ; I want to sort some 'Object' content type instances filtered by Content: Timestamp field (<= now) and sorted by Content: Timestamp field (desc).